# FactoryGirl error: uninitialized constant Post::user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, factory

I have kinda weird namespacing error dealing with [`FactoryGirl`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). The model is `Post ⤞ User`.
The code is:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'active_record'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base ; end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :moderator, class_name: :user
end

::FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Ghghghgh Ghghg'
  end
  factory :post do
    text 'Lorem ipsum etc'
    association :moderator, factory: :user, strategy: :create
  end
end
```

It is required fine, returning `true`. Now when I try to produce an instance, I get this error:

```
FactoryGirl.create :post
#⇒ NameError: uninitialized constant Post::user
```

What obvious am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
has_one :moderator, class_name: :user
```

There's no class named `user`; the class's name is `User`. You want this:

```
has_one :moderator, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you. I mixed up things and continued to write AR code in `FactoryGirl`-like manner. Fresh eye is a great power. Thank you.